# How to use BarCode scanner in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, java.util.scanner

I have a requirement for barcode and QRCode Scanner in android Studio. After using ZXing scanner, user is forcing to instal third party scanner i.e. ZXing or it should be pre installed, I want it to be used on the current activity and also get scanned result on the same. Kindly help me in implementing the same.

Scanner View or Camera View should be on 1/3 of screen
Kindly refer the image attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcQwE.jpg)

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html. luckily barcode scanner play service api avaliable

Comment: you have to implement Zxing scanner library in your project

Comment: Try implementing this library[https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner] in your project..

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://blog.whomeninja.in/android-barcode-scanner/) holds the basic code to import the required libraries and get the code running!

**Instructions:**

Add required AAR dependencies in Gradle (github.com/embarkmobile/…)
Provide a custom layout for the capture activity.
See sample/src/main/res/layout/custom_capture_layout.xml for examples.
Set up the Scanner in your Java code:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.custom_layout); 
integrator.initiateScan();
```

For a cancel/back button, use the ids @id/zxing_back_button for zxing-android-minimal. github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal#custom-layout

Comment: Add required AAR dependencies in Gradle (https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal#adding-aar-dependency-with-gradle)
Provide a custom layout for the capture activity. See sample/src/main/res/layout/custom_capture_layout.xml for examples.
Set up the Scanner in your Java code:
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.custom_layout);
integrator.initiateScan();
For a cancel/back button, use the ids @id/zxing_back_button for zxing-android-minimal.
https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal#custom-layout

Comment: https://github.com/dimpy-chhabra/Perkey/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/dimpy/perkey/MainActivity.java

This is my implementation! SImply get this repo and try executing it! This perfectly scans QR codes and presents the data as toasts!